# Iterating with Q

Tags: node.js, mongodb, q, monk

I have this collection in MongoDB (I'm omitting `_id`s for brevity):

```
test> db.entries.find();
{
  "val": 1
}
{
  "val": 2
}
{
  "val": 3
}
{
  "val": 4
}
{
  "val": 5
}
```

I need to perform some processing on each document which I cannot do with `db.update()`. So, in a nutshell, what I need to do is retrieving one document at a time, process it in Node and save it back to Mongo.

I'm using the Monk library, and Q for promises. Here's what I've done — I didn't include the processing/save bit for brevity:

```
var q = require('q');

var db = require('monk')('localhost/test');
var entries = db.get('entries');

var i = 1;
var total;

var f = function (entry) {
    console.log('i = ' + i);
    console.log(entry.val);
    i++;
    if (i <= total) {
        var promise = entries.findOne({ val: i });
        loop.then(function (p) {
            return f(p);
        });
        return promise;
    }
};

var loop = q.fcall(function () {

    return entries.count({});

}).then(function (r) {

    total = r;
    return entries.findOne({ val: i });

}).then(f);
```

I would expect this code to print out:

```
i = 1
1
i = 2
2
i = 3
3
i = 4
4
i = 5
5
```

but it actually prints out:

```
i = 1
1
i = 2
2
i = 3
2
i = 4
2
i = 5
2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I changed slightly the `loop.then()` bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, loop is one and only one promise. It is executed only once. It is not a function.
Inside `f`, `loop.then(f)` just trigger `f` with the result of the promise (it has already been executed so it is not executed again).

You actually want to create several promises.
What you are looking for is something that should looks like:

```
var q = require('q');

var db = require('monk')('localhost/test');
var entries = db.get('entries');

var i = 1;
var total;

var f = function (entry) {
    console.log('i = ' + i);
    console.log(entry.val);
    i++;
    if (i <= total) {
        // I am not sure why you put entries.findOne here (looks like a mistake, 
        // its returned value isn't used) but if you really need it to be done
        // before loop, then you must pipe it before loop
        return entries.findOne({ val: i }).then(loop);
        // do not pipe f again here, it is already appended at the end of loop
    }
};

function loop(){
    return q.fcall(function () {
        return entries.count({});
    }).then(function (r) {
        total = r;
        return entries.findOne({ val: i });
    }).then(f);
}

loop();
```

If you are interested, [here is a very nice article about promises](http://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html).

Comment: Thanks, that worked a treat. There is still something I haven't really grasped about promises. Any ideas about how to remove the duplicate `entries.findOne()` call?

Comment: In the body of `f`, you can just remove `entries.findOne` and just call loop as you would for any normal function.

Comment: The result value of a function piped to a promise (e.g. with `then`) is used as a filter to the resulting promise. If it is another promise, this other promise is piped at its turn. If it is any other value, this value will be the result of the promise chain (which is actually another promise). It is hard to explain in detail the promise mechanism here, but I really advise you to have a look at the link I put at the end of my answer.